# Why is "all sites" not in alphabetical order in the Stack Exchange button menu?

Tags: support

At the top of the screen there is a "Stack Exchange" dropdown menu. It contains "hot questions", "all sites", and "inbox".

I'm using the "all sites" to switch between the different Stack Exchange sites im intrested in, but finding the right one is more difficult than it needs to be.

Why is this list not sorted alphabetically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only took a year to answer this, but I found the answer!

[It's ordered by your reputation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85872/149432)

Presumably, sites where you have the most reputation are the ones you want to access most frequently.

Comment: Sites where you have 200+ rep are ordered by reputation. Everything else is unsorted as far as I know.

Comment: Nope. Thats not it. My order: 
"Stackoverflow", "Programmers", "Japanese Language"... 
The two first are right, the third is very very wrong.. Dont even have an account there, and I have accounts at other SE sites.

Comment: Or should I take it; this is the way it is supposed to work and any other behaviour should be reported as a bug?

Comment: @Fredrik It's intended to be ordered by reputation for all sites where you have 200 or more rep (the threshold by which SE determines you're interested in a site). All other sites are unsorted (essentially random) as Anna notes.

Comment: Alright, fair enough, that seems correct. But how dumb is that? A random order rather than logic order? A separation of the lists at 200 points rather than a separation on where you have accounts and not? 
Sorry, not your fault, its just something I've been irritated at since I wrote the question a year ago :)